# UIPageViewController - Verifying Page Turn with alert

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a UIPageViewController to handle data entry where the last page is the active record and the previous pages are old records that can't be edited.  So I need a way to verify that the user wants to leave the last page while allowing all of the other pages to navigate as usual.

Ideally I could really use a -(BOOL)pageShouldTurn method but that doesn't exist.

Does anyone know of a way to detect if a page is about to unload then stop the page turn based on some condition?  I'm not having any luck with the gesture recognizer methods as they don't seem to be triggered even when the delegate is set.

Thanks to Michael, I've added this to my pageViewController which does exactly what I needed:

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pvc willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers
{
    if ([pvc.viewControllers.lastObject pageIndex] == [self.pageDataSource.allObjects count]) {
        UIAlertView *alertDialog;
        alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                       initWithTitle:@"Are You Done?"
                       message:@"Once you leave this page you can't edit this record again"
                       delegate:self
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertDialog show];
    }
}
```

So the alert box stops the page from turning only once. When it is dismissed, the user can then change the page. My version checks to make sure this only happens on the last page, you could remove the 'if' statement and alert on every page turn, but that would be annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me there are at least two options.

Number one, you have ["`- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDelegateProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIPageViewControllerDelegate/pageViewController%3awillTransitionToViewControllers%3a).  You might be able to catch a transition there and deny / force the old page to be reset.

Or, you can now subclass "`UIPageViewController`" and in your subclassed controller, you can define a new delegate protocol (incorporating all the original `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`" methods) and you can add your own "`-(BOOL) pageShouldTurn`" protocol method.

Both of these possibilities require iOS 6.

Comment: Thanks Michael, both look like good options.  Let me play with it and I'll get back to you.  (I'm working with iOS 6, so no problems there)

Comment: I wasn't aware of the willTransitionToViewControllers method, so thanks for that for sure! Then I had to identify my current page which wasn't too tough. I'm adding my final method above to help anyone else who may need this.  Thanks again!